# How do I shorten my main method to where it still functions?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, integer

I  have a java code to read the length of an integer array, output the range, length of the gap, and any distinct elements inside. Additionally, it will output the numbers again with none repeated.
I  would like to shorten the length of my main method.
My code produces the correct output, it is just very lengthy. Additionally, is there a way I  can edit this main method to where it won't require a drastic change to my other methods? Thank you so much!

```
package ArrayPrograms;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class WIP{
      
    static int LargestGap(int [] a, int n)
     {
         int diff = Math.abs(a[1] - a[0]);
          for(int i = 1; i < a.length-1; i++)
              if(Math.abs(a[i+1]-a[i]) > diff)
                  diff = Math.abs(a[i+1] - a[i]);
          return diff;
     }
    
    int range(int a[], int n)
        {
        
        int max1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                if (Math.abs(a[i] - a[j]) > max1)
                {
                    max1 = Math.abs(a[i] - a[j]);
                }
            }
        }
            return max1;
        
        }
            
    int numberOfDistinctElement(int a[], int n) 
    {
         int num = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            {
                int j = 0;
                for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
                    if (a[i] == a[j])
                        break;
                if (i == j)
                    num++;
            }
            return num;
        }
    
    int[] distinctElements(int a[], int n,int numberofDistinct)
    {
      int index = 0;  
       int[] distinct= new int[numberofDistinct];  
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)   
        {   
            int flag = 0;  
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){  
                if (a[i] == a[j]){   
                    flag = 1;  
                    break;   
                }  
            }  
            if (flag == 0){   
                distinct[index] = a[i];  
                index++;    
            }  
        }
            return distinct;
        } 
        
    ***public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
        
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;

        WIP obj=new WIP();
        System.out.print("Enter the length of the array:");
        num = in.nextInt();
        
        int array[] = new int[num];
        
        System.out.print("Enter the elements of the array: ");
        
        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            array[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        
        System.out.println("The largest gap in the array is "+WIP.LargestGap(array,num)+".");
        System.out.println("The range of the array is  "+obj.range(array,num)+".");
        
        int numberofDistinct=obj.numberOfDistinctElement(array,num);
        
        System.out.println("The number of distinct elements is  "+numberofDistinct+".");
        
        int[] distinctArray=obj.distinctElements(array,num,numberofDistinct);
        
        System.out.print("The array of distinct elements is ["); 
            
        for (int i = 0; i < distinctArray.length; i++) 
            
            if(i== distinctArray.length-1)
            {
                System.out.print(distinctArray[i]+"]");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print( distinctArray[i]+ ",");  
            }
               
            in.close();
        }
    }***
```

Comment: "_I would like to shorten the length of my main method. My code produces the correct output, it is just very lengthy_" - then this might not be the right place for your question. This might fit better over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: How would you want to shorten that method and why? Of course you could use Java convention of putting opening curlies on the same line as the statement that opens the block or move some of the printing code to separate methods. Other than that the only thing I see that could be shortened a little would be that last loop (`Arrays.toString(distinctArray)`). [codereview.se] would probably be the better place for such a question though.

Comment: Btw, it looks like you've tripped over your own formatting since you seem to have marked the end of `main()` in the wrong place. And I'd also highly recommend using curly braces for that last for loop as well (but don't accidentally put that `in.close()` into the loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure thing. Here you go:

```
package arrayprograms;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class WIP{

    static int LargestGap(int [] a, int n)
    {
        int diff = Math.abs(a[1] - a[0]);
        for(int i = 1; i < a.length-1; i++)
            if(Math.abs(a[i+1]-a[i]) > diff)
                diff = Math.abs(a[i+1] - a[i]);
        return diff;
    }

    int range(int a[], int n)
    {

        int max1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                if (Math.abs(a[i] - a[j]) > max1)
                {
                    max1 = Math.abs(a[i] - a[j]);
                }
            }
        }
        return max1;

    }

    int numberOfDistinctElement(int a[], int n) 
    {
        int num = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            int j = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
                if (a[i] == a[j])
                    break;
            if (i == j)
                num++;
        }
        return num;
    }

    int[] distinctElements(int a[], int n,int numberofDistinct)
    {
        int index = 0;  
        int[] distinct= new int[numberofDistinct];  
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)   
        {   
            int flag = 0;  
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){  
                if (a[i] == a[j]){   
                    flag = 1;  
                    break;   
                }  
            }  
            if (flag == 0){   
                distinct[index] = a[i];  
                index++;    
            }  
        }
        return distinct;
    } 

    static void showResults(int[] array, int num, WIP obj){
        System.out.println("The largest gap in the array is "+WIP.LargestGap(array,num)+".");
        System.out.println("The range of the array is  "+obj.range(array,num)+".");

        int numberofDistinct=obj.numberOfDistinctElement(array,num);

        System.out.println("The number of distinct elements is  "+numberofDistinct+".");

        int[] distinctArray=obj.distinctElements(array,num,numberofDistinct);

        System.out.print("The array of distinct elements is ["); 

        for (int i = 0; i < distinctArray.length; i++) 

            if(i== distinctArray.length-1)
            {
                System.out.print(distinctArray[i]+"]");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print( distinctArray[i]+ ",");  
            }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;

        WIP obj=new WIP();
        System.out.print("Enter the length of the array:");
        num = in.nextInt();

        int array[] = new int[num];

        System.out.print("Enter the elements of the array: ");

        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            array[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        in.close();

        showResults(array, num, obj );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not a whole lot you can do, like most of the comments say, but you can remove and edit some of the braces around that aren't necessary for the bodies. Here is a rough draft of it. The only things you could change besides that is to store all of the WIP.tests in variables in one code block and then print them all out in another code block; which would improve readability.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

Scanner in  = new Scanner(System.in);
WIP     obj = new WIP();

System.out.print("Enter the length of the array:");
int num = in.nextInt();
int array[] = new int[num] ;

System.out.print("Enter the elements of the array: ");

for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    array[i] = in.nextInt();

System.out.println("The largest gap in the array is " + WIP.LargestGap(array,num) + ".");
System.out.println("The range of the array is  " + obj.range(array,num) + ".");

int numberofDistinct = obj.numberOfDistinctElement( array, num );
System.out.println("The number of distinct elements is  "+numberofDistinct+".");
int[] distinctArray = obj.distinctElements(array,num,numberofDistinct);

System.out.print("The array of distinct elements is ["); 
    
for (int i = 0; i < distinctArray.length; i++) 
    if(i== distinctArray.length-1)
        System.out.print(distinctArray[i]+"]");
    else
        System.out.print( distinctArray[i]+ ",");  
       
    in.close();
}
```